# How to enter a URL into a smartphone without doing a search?

Tags: url

Scenario: I'm talking in-person with someone and during the course of conversation I think of a website whose URL I know from memory, and I want them to type the URL into their smartphone and access the website directly without performing a web search (just like you could do on a traditional computer web browser in the address bar).

To be clear: I don't want it to do "search as you type", I don't want it to create suggestions based on partial matches, and I don't want it to do any kind of search that delivers search results. I don't want the entered string to be sent to a search engine to do any processing of any kind. I just want it to open a connection to the indicated website (i.e., go directly to DNS lookup followed by HTTP or HTTPS connection to the entered URL). Also, in this scenario, I have no way to generate a QR code for them (I don't own a smartphone, and might not be carrying my computer with me).

Do smartphones have that facility (i.e., a field to enter a URL without passing it to a search engine, exactly like the old browsers used to do with the address bar)? If so, how do I instruct the Android user (and/or iOS user) to find the field where they can type in the URL and not have it be processed by a search engine?

Comment: I don't see a problem here, just check the different browser apps for an option to disable the automatic search. This has nothing to do with Android, just with the browser app you are using - I assume you are using Chrome by default.

Comment: You can even configure Chrome the way you want: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/privacy-settings-chrome-android/

Comment: That doesn't work. The people in the scenario I described are non-technical. They don't even know if they're using Chrome or not. Also, they usually don't want to hand me their phone to make config changes (like I'm sitting next to them in a bar, or meetup group). I just wanted to know what button to tell them to push to make it do the thing I described (just like on a computer browser). If there is one, great. If there isn't, there isn't.

Comment: Then I only have one suggestion left: Don't enter the URL, use a QR code instead the the URL is sent as one to the web browser and the address bar search and suggestion feature is not used. Anyway if you want to keep URLs secret you are doing something wrong - use a password protected site instead.

Comment: Thanks for the note. I might not be able to generate a QR code on short notice (as I don't normally carry such devices myself) and might not know in advance what QR codes I might want. Also, the point wasn't to keep the URL secret, it was to see if smartphones have the equivalent function as the computer web browser.  If it doesn't, it doesn't. I'm OK with that, if that's the answer.

Comment: I am sorry but your question does not make sense to me if you don't care about the privacy of the URL. If you want to enter an URL just enter in in the web browser and just ignore that it performs autocomplete in the background. If you keep on entering the url the entered url will be used. May be you should edit your question and create a real example how and why you want to disable autocomplete (the "how" I already explained to you).

Comment: It wasn't just about autocomplete, it was about what I specified in the original question (just asking if a certain functionality exists). I have my answer already so I won't add to the question (in order to avoid adding additional confusion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summary (after one month): "No can do." The functionality of entering a URL without doing a search (as it exists on computer browsers) does not exist on smartphones conveniently (i.e., without doing some kind of obscure config changes or app installation, which would not be suitable to do in the scenario described in the original question).

Answer (score 2):

These days, browsers on mobile devices, use one bar for searching with an search engine and inserting a specific URL request of web site. 
What you need to do is simple tell them "***Touch top bar/address bar and insert this specific URL***" or "***Insert this URL in the bar and send***".
You need to know that if the inserted text is a correctly formatted URL (`protocol://domainOrIPAddress:port/path/filename`) then the browser will show you directly the web page, otherwise it will use the default search engine for retrieving a possible list of sites that you maybe want to see for the inserted keyword.

In summary, you don't need something special, everything should work without you doing anything on browser settings. However I think there is an option to deactivate the bar for searching cases and only use it for inserting URL, but it's more convenient how it works normally, so by default is one bar for searching and URL request in all browsers.

However, for not letting search engines look on your search/request you need to uncheck some settings on browsers like "***Suggestions by Search Engine/Bookmarks***".

Comment: It didn't work.  I followed your instructions on a friend's smartphone and it did a "search as you type" displaying a list of search results, indicating that the URL was passed to a search engine (which is exactly what I said I don't want).

Comment: Sorry I mistook your question on this part. Like on desktop browsers there are some setting that you can play with. The name is browser dependent but in general there is a checkbox "activate suggestion by provider" or "activate suggestion by history". You need to uncheck this options. So you need to say  "**Go on settings** -> **Uncheck/Remove setting**" and after that go to search bar and write this URL. Hope this helps and I'll update the answer after your veriffication

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about browser dependent.  The people I'm referring to either aren't using a browser or aren't aware of one being there.  They are non-technical.  Also, disabling their ability to do a normal search seems a bit severe.  I wasn't looking for a solution that disables any normal capability, nor one that requires complex reconfiguration (or installing an app, or coding, installing another OS, etc...  even though I know all of those solutions might exist).  This might be some person in a bar and I just want them to go to some URL without it being recorded by google etc.

Comment: Sorry man, but Internet is a public so in reality even the providers could _theoretically speaking_ register your requests for looking in them. You need to give them faith that they aren't looking. When you send a packet on the network, especially with technology wireless like WI-FI every one can sniff your packets and if they aren't encrypted easily look what you have requested. In the end if they are interested they will look. However you can use some other services to have more privacy like VPN and so one, but its maybe over kill for your case.

Comment: In the end if you don't want to be recorded the best way is to create a personal program that makes the request in an encrypted communication like _TLS_, or use some service like _**VPN, DuckDuckGo**_ and _**Tor**_ having faith in what they promise. However there will be obviously a trace that you are using this service, but Google for example will not know what you were doing in this sessions. So sorry, but there isn't a easy solution to not be tracked with the basic app that we are normally using (default browsers and so on)

Comment: Thanks for your efforts to respond, but the key issue is not whether it is recorded (that was just an example of an effect of passing to a search engine, hence the "etc."), it was simply to not pass the results to a search engine (as stated in the original post).  I'm aware of the underlying workings of the Internet, I was just trying to find out whether or not smartphones have (without substantial config changes, apps, or programming) a space for entering a URL without performing a search (just like browsers do, or did).  That is what I wanted to know.  Other considerations are not important.

Comment: No there isn't a default component which do that, maybe on a very specific but not the most used ones. You need to change some settings for not using the address bar with search engines and only for inserting URL otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for Chrome, but I stumbled on the solution. You type the address in the bar, then hold it. Initially just one word is selected with the cursor (like when you delete characters), but if you keep holding it down the whole address will be selected and a few icons will come up at the top. One of the icons is "open" so you just tap that and the requested page will open instead of doing a search.

Answer (score 0):

**Note: my answer is speculative, so take with a grain of salt and YMMV, etc.**

You can access the Chrome internal page located at...

`chrome://omnibox`

...and play around with the options to potentially achieve what you're looking for.  The notable options include the `zero suggest` and `prevent inline autocomplete` toggles.  However, please note I have not tested these functions myself and hence cannot say for certain they will produce the desired results; if you have the time and desire to do so, [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/omnibox/#type-DefaultSuggestResult) is the official resource regarding that internal page.

Another thought I had was that you can use *any* text-field outside of the browser to type your URL, and then switch over to the browser and directly paste the url into the omnibox.

Finally, there should be several ways to access a terminal emulator, which then gives you the option to directly open whatever literal URL you input as a command.  I can't speak for certain, but I would make the assumption that this would circumvent autocomplete; in fact, you might test this with, say, a shortcut widget/application or other indirect means available to call on a URI you specify (e.g., generating the URL into a hyperlink in a word processor and clicking it; also works in Excel/Sheets with the `hyperlink()` function, etc).

Whether or not these are acceptable depends on your intent behind your question, as it's a bit ambiguous even after reading the OP over several times: do you not want any autocomplete entry logs?  On server-side or device-side?  Do you simply not want to **visually** see autocomplete predictions populating in-line as you type?  Is your concern privacy-centric (in regards to ISP, or the device owner, etc), or some other criteria?  I know you've tried to narrow your question down to be more context-specific, but understanding these facets would help the community be better able to answer your question and perhaps even qualify workarounds that might otherwise have been neglected.